# How to get only first value in ngrx action in angular component?

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

Problem: I need to get response. At first will be called:

```
        this.store.dispatch(new UpdateRequest(data));
```

then, if success, response will be in :

```
        this.actions.pipe(ofType(ActionTypes.UPDATE_SUCCESS))
```

or if error:

```
        this.actions.pipe(ofType(ActionTypes.UPDATE_ERROR))
```

before ngrx it was easy:

```
this.service.update(data).subscribe((data) => this.update(data)));
```

with ngrx :
A) without take(1):

```
        this.store.dispatch(new UpdateRequest(data));
```

```
    const success$ = this.actions.pipe(ofType(ActionTypes.UPDATE_SUCCESS))
        .pipe(
            takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        )
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.update();
            success$.unsubscribe();
            error.unsubscribe();
        });

    const error$ = this.actions.pipe(ofType(ActionTypes.UPDATE_ERROR))
        .pipe(
            takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        )
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.error();
            success$.unsubscribe();
            error.unsubscribe();
        });
```

B) with take(1):
this.store.dispatch(new UpdateRequest(data));

```
    const success$ = this.actions.pipe(ofType(ActionTypes.UPDATE_SUCCESS))
        .pipe(
            take(1),
            takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        )
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.update();
            error.unsubscribe();
        });

    const error$ = this.actions.pipe(ofType(ActionTypes.UPDATE_ERROR))
        .pipe(
            take(1),
            takeUntil(this.destroy$),
        )
        .subscribe(() => {
            this.error();
            success$.unsubscribe();
        });
```

And in ngOnDestroy:

```
ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
}
```

But in ngrx take(1) is forbidden for action : https://github.com/cartant/eslint-plugin-rxjs/blob/main/docs/rules/no-unsafe-first.md

So, maybe you know better way of subscribing only first value in actions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `take(1)` in your case, because you're using the `actions$` outside the `@Effect`.

The mentioned `forbidden` is related to complete the `effect` observable, which will cause the `effect` to not handle the action anymore:

> Avoid completing effects and epics.
> This rule effects failures if first is used in an effect or epic in a manner that will complete the outermost observable.